# Make a user object property resolved inside @FieldResolver (posts)

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I am creating a reddit clone, using a type-graphql, express-graphql and typegoose,

first i run a query for posts and i get the user info (_id, username) :

```
query posts {
  posts {
    _id
    title
    image
    body
    user {
      _id
      username
    }
    subredditList {
      topic
      _id
    }
    createdAt
  }
}
```

but when i run query for subreddit to get all posts that belong to that subreddit, i get a user is null

the query i run for subreddit:

```
query subreddit($topic: String!) {
  subreddit(input: { topic: $topic }) {
    _id
    topic
    posts {
      _id # works fine
      title # works fine
      body # works fine
      image # works fine
          
      # the user is null !!, i get user: null
      user {
        _id
        username
      }

      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

I get user: null even when the posts field in Subreddit object type is resolved

Subreddit object type:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class Subreddit {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ required: true })
  topic: string;

  @Field(() => [Post])
  posts: Post[]; // i get all info exept the user object

  @Field(() => String)
  createdAt: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  updatedAt: string;
}
```

Subreddit resolver:

```js
@Resolver(() => Subreddit, {})
export default class SubredditResolver {
  constructor(private readonly subredditService: SubredditService) {
    this.subredditService = new SubredditService();
  }

  @Query(() => [Subreddit])
  async subreddits() {
    return this.subredditService.subreddits();
  }

  @Query(() => Subreddit, { nullable: true })
  async subreddit(@Arg("input") input: GetSubredditByTopic) {
    return this.subredditService.subreddit(input);
  }

  @Mutation(() => Subreddit)
  async createSubreddit(
    @Arg("input") input: CreateSubredditInput
  ): Promise<Subreddit> {
    return this.subredditService.createSubreddit(input);
  }

  // here where i resolve the "posts" field in my Subreddit object type
  @FieldResolver(() => Post, {})
  async posts(@Root() subreddit: Subreddit) {
    console.log(args);
    return this.subredditService.posts(subreddit);
  }
}
```

and finally the resolver function is like this:

```js
async posts(input: Subreddit) {
  try {
    const posts = await PostModel.find({ subredditId: input._id });

    return posts;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error("Couldn't get the posts");
  }
}
```

Here is my Post object type looks like:

```js
@ObjectType()
export class Post {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ required: true })
  title: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ required: true })
  body: string;

  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
  @prop({})
  image: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @prop({ ref: () => Subreddit })
  subredditId: Ref<Subreddit>;

  @Field(() => [Subreddit])
  subredditList: [Subreddit];

  @Field(() => [Comment])
  comments: Comment[];

  // note that the "user" field is string refers to id of the user,
  @Field(() => User, { nullable: true })
  @prop({ ref: () => User })
  user: Ref<User>;

  @Field(() => Date)
  createdAt: Date;

  @Field(() => Date)
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Post resolver:

```
@Resolver(() => Post)
export default class PostResolver {
  constructor(private readonly postService: PostService) {
    this.postService = new PostService();
  }

  @Query(() => [Post])
  async posts() {
    return this.postService.posts();
  }

  @Authorized()
  @Mutation(() => Post)
  async createPost(
    @Arg("input") input: CreatePostInput,
    @Ctx() context: Context
  ): Promise<Post> {
    return this.postService.createPost(input, context);
  }

  @FieldResolver()
  async subredditList(@Root() post: Post) {
    return this.postService.subredditList(post);
  }

  // here i resolve the user field in my Post object type, and it works fine
  @FieldResolver()
  async user(@Root() post: Post) {
    return this.postService.user(post);
  }
}
```

the resolver function for "user" field in Post object type:

```
async user(input: Post) {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({
      _id: input.user,
    }).lean();
    return user;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error("Couldn't get the user");
  }
}
```

the property "user" from post query is resolved but when i run subreddit query i get user is null .

any help please ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(input)` in `async user(...) {...}`. I think something is wrong here. Moreover, reading through [Typegoose docs about `Ref`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/types/ref-type/) it should be `Ref<User, string>`?

Comment: you are right, i get huge object, and document i want is in "_doc" property so it's input._doc._id, but when i run query for posts i just get the document alone,

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be that you are missing setting the type for arrays, like:

```
class YourClass {
  // ...
  @Field(() => [Post])
  posts: Post[];
  // ...
}
```

but it would need to be like:

```
class YourClass {
  // ...
  @Field(() => [Post])
  @prop({ type: () => [Post] })
  posts: Post[];
  // ...
}
```

see [Quick-Start-Guide](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide)

> `type` has to be defined when working with Arrays, because Reflection only returns basic information. [Look here for why](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7169)
> Like `public: string[]` is in reflection only `Array`.

or the note in [@prop: Array Options](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop#array-options)

> Option `type` must be provided, otherwise the array will result in `Mixed` read typegoose issue [#300](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/300) for more info

---

Note: i dont know if anything is wrong with your graphql setup

---

i also read in the comments that there is supposedly a `_doc` property, which is internal in mongoose and should never be shown, but it gets exposed instead of properly translated due to a problem with `class-transformer`, the only workaround is to use `@Exclude()` for the whole class (or globally) and only `@Expose()` the proper properties, also see [Integration Examples: Using with class-transformer](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/integration-examples/using-with-class-transformer)